# OPENCV - Use svm file in python that was trainned in opencv c++ is possible?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, svm

I've trained a face recognition system using c++ opencv. I did some tests and the recognition works very well in c++ code so i saved a file with this trainning. When I try to load this file on python the predictions are always 0.0. I'm very new with python and numpy arrays. Below I'll write the code in c++ (that works) and in python that load the image and apply the prediction.

> C++ ( Working very well )

```
Mat face;
face = frame( faceRect );
// Convert to grayscale
cvtColor( face, face, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
// Equalize hist
equalizeHist( face, face );
// Resize to 60x60
resize( face, face, samplesSize );
// Convert to CV_32FC1
face.convertTo( face, CV_32FC1 );
// Reshape to a row vector, 1x3600
face = face.reshape( 1, 1 );
// Make prediction
float prediction = svm.predict( face, true );
cout << "Predicao: " << prediction << endl;
```

> Python:

```
def faceRecogntion( self, faceRoi):
    # 1- Convert to grayscale
    grayface = cv2.cvtColor(faceRoi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # 2- Equalize hist
    cv2.equalizeHist( grayface, grayface)
    # 3 - Resize it to 60x60
    dim = ( 60, 60)
    grayface = cv2.resize(grayface, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    print 'Image size: ' + str(grayface.shape)
    # 4 - Convert to 32F
    faceFloat = np.array(grayface, dtype=np.float32);
    faceFloat = faceFloat.reshape( -1, 3600)
    # 5- Apply prediction
    result = self.svm.predict( faceFloat )
    print result
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    return
```

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you set `returnDFVal` to `true` inside the [`predict()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html#cvsvm-predict) function and in this case if your problem is 2-class classification then the method returns the decision function value that is signed distance to the margin, you should try to modify predict:

```
faceFloat = np.float32(grayface).reshape(-1, 3600)
result = self.svm.predict(faceFloat, True)
```

p.s.:
Does `face` in C++ contains the same elements (in the same order) as `faceFloat` in python?